# F# - need help for someone to explain Lazy Functions and why I am getting a certain result

Tags: f#

I have a question on why I am getting certain results in F#. I have the following code...

```
let lHelloWorld = lazy(printfn "Lazy Hello World"; 30+30)
let aHelloWorld = (printfn "Active Hello World"; 30+30)

printfn "lazy value is %d"  lHelloWorld.Value 
printfn "lazy value is %d"  lHelloWorld.Value
printfn "active value is %d"  aHelloWorld
printfn "active value is %d"  aHelloWorld
```

My output is as follows...

```
Active Hello World
Lazy Hello World
lazy value is 60
lazy value is 60
active value is 60
active value is 60
```

What I can't understand is this... Why is active hello world's printfn being shown before lazy hello word? I would have expected "Lazy Hello World" to have been shown before "Active Hello World"?

If anyone can help explain this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not a big F# person but with lazy patterns it is set so they don't do anything until they are request. So when you wrap that in lazy it won't run until you actually use it. But since you didn't use that for the active one it performed the function as soon as it was assigned.

This is just a guess though as I am not a F# guy.

Here is an article that explains it as well.
http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/03/21/adventures-in-f-f-101-part-6-lazy-evaluation.aspx

Sorry forgot to attach the link.

Comment: I would have thought that I would have to call the force for the lazy function for it to be called?

Comment: Well you are requesting the value so that triggers the lazy function in the variable to run and assign the result. Since the first assignment is wrapped in lazy it is basically ignored and not assigned. But the second one calls the print and then makes the assignment. The lazy one is assigned when you first request it.

Comment: Okay.. a blonde moment from me - for some reason I thought that the functions would only be called when they were needed, with side effects.

Now that I look at it, I C# terms it seems like when the "functions" were created by default in order that they are declared - but a lazy function is only created when it is first used regardless of the order that it is declared.

Comment: yeah I know how those go. I had one earlier today that drove me crazy for two days. Glad to help.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my annotated description

```
// Here we go...
let lHelloWorld = lazy(printfn "Lazy Hello World"; 30+30) 
// Ok, we defined a value called lHelloWorld.  The right hand side is 
// a lazy(...), so we don't evaluate the ..., we just store it in a
// System.Lazy object and assign that value to lHelloWorld.

let aHelloWorld = (printfn "Active Hello World"; 30+30) 
// Ok, we're defining a value called aHelloWorld.  The right hand side is
// a normal expression, so we evaluate it it right now.  Which means we
// print "Active Hello World", and then compute 30+30=60, and assign the
// final result (60) to aHelloWorld.

// Note that neither of the previous two entities are functions.


// Now we have some effects:
printfn "lazy value is %d"  lHelloWorld.Value  
// Calling .Value on an object of type System.Lazy will either
//  - force the value if it has not yet been evaluated, or
//  - return the cached value if it was previously evaluated
// Here we have not yet evaluated it, so we force the evaluation, 
// which prints "Lazy Hello World" and then computes 30+30=60, and then
// stores the final 60 value in the lHelloWorld's cache.  Having evaluated 
// the arguments to the printfn on this line of code, we can now call that
// printfn, which prints "lazy value is 60".

printfn "lazy value is %d"  lHelloWorld.Value 
// This time, calling .Value just fetches the already-computed cached value,
// 60, and so this just prints "lazy value is 60".

printfn "active value is %d"  aHelloWorld 
// aHelloWorld has type 'int'.  Its value is 60.  This is trivial, 
// it prints "active value is 60".
printfn "active value is %d"  aHelloWorld 
// Ditto.
```